# Asp.Net Core Middleware Response Redirect URL incomplete hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

I have an application hosted on IIS. I am using middleware to detect if the logged-in user has to change their password after the password has been reset by an admin. When I try to redirect the response to the razor page for changing the password, the redirect seems to be incomplete due to the missing virtual directory path. This results in a `Server Error 404 - File or directory not found`.

Expected URL: myDomain/**FOLDER**/Identity/Account/ChangePassword

Actual URL: myDomain/Identity/Account/ChangePassword

My middleware redirect section looks like this:

```cs
    var returnUrl = context.Request.Path.Value == "/" ? string.Empty : "?returnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.Path.Value);
        
    string location= "/Identity/Account/ChangePassword";
    context.Response.Redirect(location + returnUrl);
    await _next(context);
```

Comment: The word `folder` is not in your code. Where are you expecting it to come from?

Comment: Yes I know... I also tried "~/Identity/Account/ChangePassword" but that does not work either.

Comment: How specifically did it not work?

Comment: When using a virtual location for the redirect it results in the following: **myDomain/~/Identity/Account/ChangePassword**. 

What am I doing wrong that the tilde (~) in front of the url does not point to the root of my application?

Answer (score 0):

Beginning your redirect URL with "/" will always scope to your domain, e.g.

```
// Current URL: https://localhost:5001/Folder/Page
context.Response.Redirect("/Page2"); // navigates to: https://localhost:5001/Page2

// vs.

context.Response.Redirect("Page2"); // navigates to: https://localhost:5001/Folder/Page2
```

If you want the location to be relative to the **current directory**, drop the initial forward slash:

```cs
var returnUrl = context.Request.Path.Value == "/" 
    ? string.Empty 
    : "?returnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.Path.Value);
        
string location = "Identity/Account/ChangePassword"; // <- change here
context.Response.Redirect(location + returnUrl);
await _next(context);
```

#### UPDATE

Regarding your comment, you probably want to be using an absolute URI to the razor page (i.e. `string location = "/Folder/Identity/Account/ChangePassword";`. This will always redirect to */Folder/Identity/Account/ChangePassword* from anywhere in the app.

In summary:

- Begin the URI path with "/" to scope it to the root (i.e. the domain). Use this when referencing a path from anywhere in the app.
- Begin the URI path with a named item (e.g. a directory or a page, like "Identity") to reference it relative to the current path. Use this if the page can only be accessed from a single directory/page (or, less likely, you have a naming convention that ensures a path will always exist).

Comment: Ah okay, that did the trick but I got another problem here with the returnUrl...

Comment: ...If a user calls any other page on my website, the user will be automatically redirected back to the password change page.
Therefore the previous called page will be used as the returnUrl which is being passed as a parameter on the upcoming redirect.

The problem is that the redirect ends up with a screwed URL.

I call the following redirect: `context.Response.Redirect("Identity/Account/ChangePassword?returnUrl=%2fIdentity%2fAdministration")` but this ends up with **myDomain/Folder/Identity/Identity/Account/ChangePassword?ReturnUrl=%2fIdentity%2fAdministration** ??